# How to show the transition from equation $(4)$ to equation $(5)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show the transition between $(4)$ to $(5)$ in [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation $4$ is just an application of the multivariable chain rule, while equation $5$ uses the definition of $\dfrac{d}{dz}$.

Don't think of equation $5$ as having been derived from equation $4$. Instead, think of the right hand sides of equations $4$ and $5$ as two different expressions for the same quantity, namely $\dfrac{df}{dz}$.

Comment: Where do you get this multivariable chain rule? Any references please?

Comment: @laovultai: It is pretty standard, it should appear in any multivariable calculus text. There are also lots of sources on the internet; [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx) for example.

Comment: The multivariable chain rule would give $\frac {df} {dz} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \frac {dx} {dz} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} \frac {dy} {dz}$, not $\frac {df} {dz} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \frac {\partial x} {\partial z} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} \frac {\partial y} {\partial z}$.

Comment: Also, the $\frac \partial {\partial z}$ is a specially defined derivative, the Wirtinger derivative.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \right)$ is the [Wirtinger derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable) and therefore
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}, \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = -\frac{i}{2}.$$

**Edit:** Here are the intermediate steps (requested in a comment):
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial x }{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 -i\cdot0 \right)
= +\frac{1}{2} 
$$
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial y }{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial y}{\partial y} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(0 -i\cdot 1 \right) = -\frac{i}{2}
$$

Comment: so if $f(z)=z^2$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 2z$ and on the other hand $z^2=x^2-y^2+i2xy$, then $1/2 (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) =1/2 (2x+i2y-i(-2y+i2x))=1/2(2x+i2y+i2y+2x)=2x+i2y=2z=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ Ok.

Comment: @gammatester.. Can you explain me those two equations, why you get $1/2$ when you derivate $x$ with respect to $z$ and why you get $-i/2$ when you derivate $y$ with respecto to $z$?

Comment: @laovultai: I have just edited-in the intermediate steps

Comment: @gammatester.. As I have asked above about multivariable chain rule, I ask from you now that do they interpret in equation (4) complex function $f$ to be function of two variables $x$ and $y$ and also vector function $\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ and if yes, why it is valid to interpret complex function as vector function $\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ and why do multivariable chain rule applies to such complex function as $f$? As I know it multivariable chain rule applies only to multivariable functions like $f(x,y)=xe^y$, where $x(t)=sin(t)$ and $y(t)=e^{2t}$.

Comment: There **is** a  higher dimensional chain rule, see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions. I don't know _how
they interpret the equation_, I only gave you the hint. The
Cauchy-Riemann equations are about partial differential equations
and to quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Riemann) once
more "The Cauchy-Riemann equations [...] consist of a system of two partial
differential equations which, together with certain continuity and
differentiability criteria, form a necessary and sufficient condition for a
complex function to be complex differentiable"

Comment: @gammatester.. about relationship between complex differentiability and C-R-equations and analyticity and C-R-equations; do we agree that if $u$ and $v$ are (real) differentiable - first order derivatives exists - and $u$ and $v$ are continuous in some area $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ and C-R-equations are satisfied, then $f$ is complex differentiable in area $A$. And do we agree that if above is valid then it is also analytic at $A$? I ask this because in one lecture notes I find that they say just: "derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are continuous and satisfy C-R-eq, then f is analytic".