# Total derivative of a complex function using Wirtinger derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

The mathworld.wolfram page on [Cauchy-Riemann Equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html) states that given a complex function $f(z) = f(x,y) = u(x,y) + iy(x,y)$ has the derivative:

$$\frac {df} {dz} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \frac {\partial x} {\partial z} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} \frac {\partial y} {\partial z}$$

where the the operator $\frac {\partial} {\partial z}$ is the [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives):

[image]

I couldn't understand how was this formula for the derivative of $f(z)$ reached.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483912/how-to-show-the-transition-from-equation-4-to-equation-5

Comment: @gammatester: The multivariable chain rule would give $\frac {df} {dz} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \frac {dx} {dz} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} \frac {dy} {dz}$, not $\frac {df} {dz} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \frac {\partial x} {\partial z} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} \frac {\partial y} {\partial z}$.

Comment: Also, the $\frac \partial {\partial z}$ is a specially defined derivative, the Wirtinger derivative.